# "Unauthorized Payment" error with valid credit card in Live environment

Tags: ios, paypal

We have integrated PayPal iOS SDK version 1.1.1 into our iOS app and are testing payments in Live environment. Payment goes through without a problem when paid from a PayPal account but the credit card payment using "Pay with Card" feature doesn't seem to work.

With a valid credit card information entered, we are having an error "Unauthorized Payment" and I have no clue why we receive this error only with the credit card payment.

We have a standard business account with all tax information entered and registered our app in the developer site, from where our live client ID was obtained.

Please share if someone have had the same problem and resolved it somehow. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the same issue discussed at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/28#issuecomment-22742094?

In any case, the solution is to contact merchant technical support, as this is likely a problem with the specific account.